# Qual a diferença do HPACK para o QPACK?

Tags: http, http-headers

Muitas mudanças vieram com o HTTP 3, uma delas é o uso do QPACK em vez do HPACK (introduzido no HTTP 2) para compressão dos cabeçalhos

Qual a diferença entre eles?

Comment: A primeira letra? (Desculpe)